# Trigger - Mysql manager

Tags: mysql, triggers

I created two tables:
1) the manager
2) selling
I need to do this;
if the manager made 20 successful sales, then the premium is 20% of the sale.
I wrote so but where is the error here?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `calculate_prize_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `students` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

       UPDATE manager set
       goods = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selling WHERE manager_id = NEW.manager_id)
       WHERE id = NEW.manager_id;
       IF (goods > 20) THEN
        prize = 
        (SELECT price/0.2 FROM selling WHERE manager_id = new.manager_id);



END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should go like this -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `calculate_prize_upd` AFTER UPDATE ON `students` FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @goods varchar(100)
    SET @goods = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM selling WHERE manager_id = NEW.manager_id
    IF (goods > 20) THEN
    UPDATE selling 
    SET prize = prize * 1.2 
    WHERE manager_id = new.manager_id
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```